# Permission Denied on filezilla

Tags: wordpress, plugins, permission-denied, filezilla

I decided to deactivate and delete a plugin installed on my Wordpress site. I deactivated and deleted it from Wordpress.

Unfortunately it left me with a bunch of files and folders in wp-content that I cannot delete via Filezilla as I get a "permission denied" error. How can i get rid of them?

The plugin I am trying to completely delete is W3C Total Cache. My question does not seem to have any chances of being answered in the plugin support forum.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the folders and files in filezilla, change the permissions to "755"

Hope that will work for you!!

Comment: Does not work for me, I think :/ Permission changes but after I try to delete the file I see "permission denied" again. And if I go back to check it, the permission has changed back to 644 on its own...

Comment: Oh, in that case you need to contact to your hosting service provider, they will definitely do that for you!!